# How to List the Nearest places in the ListView

Tags: android, json, google-maps, listview, maps

I have a scenario where the nearest places such as police station, hospital, medical shops will be listed in the LISTVIEW on the basis of the specified kms range such as 5 kms radius.
I dont need to show the Google Maps but I have to show the names in the List View that is specified as the markers in Google Map View

Comment: Just use the Places API to pull distances, check those distances, and sort them.

Comment: @zgc7009: Thanks Bro...Just looking...